# Unreal Engine PIE start and stop with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unreal-engine4, airsim

I am using Airsim to test my Drone HITL.

I want to restart(Stop and start in UE4) to refresh my drone status.

I can press stop, start button but I want to do it automatically using python code.

I control drone with MAVSDK Python and hope to put stop and start code inside.

Is there Any API or Examples can I use?